# SSIS job schedule: FTP dowload csv files: Error: File represent by "..." does not found

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, ftp

I created a SSIS job to reach a csv file on remote server, but it fails every time as a scheduled job, and gives the following :

> FTP dowload csv files: Error: File represent by "/remote/file.csv"
>   does not found

but it doesn't have any problem to run manually in Microsoft visual studio.
Why does it fail as job schedule?

Answer (score 0):

Scheduled jobs run under the SQL Server Agent user.  Almost certainly this user doesn't have access to the FTP server.